# Div's contents not scaling when changing div to fit browser size?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an image defined in pixels with contents inside. I'm trying to fit the secondContainer directly inside the "hole" of the first image.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
}
#backgroundImage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/149584/149584,1206824658,1/stock-photo-old-japanese-coin-with-a-square-hole-isolated-on-white-10899223.jpg);
}
#secondContainer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  transform: translate(150px, 140px) scale(0.6);
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 2;
}
#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 10px -5px black;
  background-image: url(http://petnet-wp.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/feeding_your_cat_a_healthy_diet_can_help_prevent_illness.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="backgroundImage"></div>
  <div id="secondContainer">
    <img id="image">
  </div>
</div>
<style>
```

It fits perfectly but when I change it to

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
```

so that it stretches to fit the browser window, the second container stays where it is and the first container stretches. I want to second container to fit exactly in that position. How would I be able to maintain the proportion?

Comment: can you whip up a fiddle for us to see?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep your units in `%`, try with the `height and width`. Check this snippet:

```css
body,html {margin:0;height:100%;}
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#backgroundImage {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/149584/149584,1206824658,1/stock-photo-old-japanese-coin-with-a-square-hole-isolated-on-white-10899223.jpg);
  background-position:center;
}
#secondContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height:14%;
  left:50%;
  top:48%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 2;
  background:url('http://petnet-wp.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/feeding_your_cat_a_healthy_diet_can_help_prevent_illness.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size:contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="backgroundImage"></div>
  <div id="secondContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify relative sizes and positioning to the parent, meaning that you need to use percentages instead of pixels.
It does not matter how big the parent is, the ratio will remain the same for the child to be contained in the gap.
After a bit of experimentation I found that the following percentages will resolve your issue.

```
#secondContainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(40%);
  top: calc(40%);
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

Explanation:

- Firstly, you don't have to use transform for this task, so I removed it.
- You want to have the size of the child div proportional to the parent, which in this case, is 20%. This way it will always fit the gap.
- To keep the child div centered in the parent div, specify *top* and *left* attributes with percentages, again. The value needed is **50% - half of its size**, which in this case, is 40% both in width and height.

I uploaded the code to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/y5xLdaoj/2/). You will see that it is not pefectly centered - it is because the image in the back has the text at the bottom, therefore the gap is not exactly at the middle.